# Is a smooth function characterized by its value on any (non-empty) open interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Do there exist smooth $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \neq g$, but $f(x) = g(x)\ \ \forall\ x \in (a, b)$ (assume $a < b$)?

Comment: Are folks allergic to 1-line questions or something? Why are people closing this question?

Comment: You have not shared your own thoughts on the problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: I guess my thoughts were, "I think there probably exists an example, but I haven't been able to think of any", which is why I asked the question. Is that all there was to it?

Comment: I did not vote to close your question, but it is best to share your thoughts on the problem and indicate where you are stuck to protect your question from being closed.  Happily, you received a good answer to your question.

Comment: I *strongly* second the OP: this is a good self-contained question. I myself wouldn't add any detail to it. Questions like this (asking for subtle examples or counter-examples) are not trivial, therefore it is absolutely acceptable for a student not to know how to approach them. The users who voted to close this should have given it more attention and not behave like "serial closers".

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2135470/a-smooth-function-can-not-be-transformed-into-another-smooth-function-without-ch

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canonical example:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac 1x} &\text{if }x>0 \\ 0 &\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$$

is smooth and equal to the zero function on the interval $(-\infty, 0)$, but is not the zero function.

Comment: +1 Wow, thanks. I even knew about $e^{-1/x^2}$ but for some reason it never hit me to try $e^{-1/x}$...

Comment: @Mehrdad: $\Bbb e ^{- \frac 1 {x^2}}$ is equally good, the important thing is the branch of the definition where $f=0$.

Comment: @AlexM.: The issue with $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ is it's only zero at the origin, making me doubt if the same thing would be true if we were talking about intervals rather than points.

Comment: @Mehrdad : Probably Alex mean $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac 1{x^2}} &\text{if }x>0 \\ 0 &\text{if }x\le 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @JohnMa: Yeah, the problem was it never hit me to try to use a different definition for the left half plane (I was just thinking of the function by itself).

Comment: @JohnMa: Yes, that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @JohnMa Does such an example exist that has no trivial component (i.e. isn't defined as 0 for some interval).